# Why this simple MySQL query is so slow?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, where-clause

So here is a very simple table 'tbl':

```
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| val     | varchar(45)         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| id      | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And indexes for it:

```
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| tbl    |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |   201826018 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl    |          1 | val      |            1 | val         | A         |      881336 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

I'm trying this simple select:

```
select val from tbl where val = 'iii';
```

result: 86208 rows in set (0.08 sec)

But when I want to slightly modify it:

```
select id, val from tbl where val = 'iii';
```

the result is: 86208 rows in set (47.30 sec)

I have an index right on the coumn that where points to, all I'm modifying is the result rows representation. 
Why there is so terrifying delay? (I have to say that I can't reproduce this delay every time I want: even after 'reset query cache' or setting 'query_cache_type=off' command it can be done quickly).

Comment: You could try running `EXPLAIN`, but is suspect that this is more of an server related issue.

Comment: Why would you select 86 thousand fields and do that of TWO columns? I think the problem here is the logic of the query :/ Maybe you should share what you are to achieve?

Comment: +1 well-asked question with the pertinent data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without actually examining your server configuration it is hard to tell, but here's an educated guess.  In the first instance, MySQL is able to satisfy your query without actually reading the table data.  All the information you have asked for can be retrieved from the index alone.  Notice that the cardinality of the `val` index is only on the order of 10<sup>6</sup> rows, and the rows are going to be very short in the index.

In the second case you have asked for data NOT in the index on `val`. Now the engine has to actually find and read rows from the data.  Here the cardinality is about 250 times larger, and since the index will retrieve rows ordered by `val`, finding the corresponding `id` values will require A LOT of jumping around in several hundred gigs of data on disk.  This is going to be very much slower.

Comment: Yes, proper tuple index did the thing. Thank you and please visit my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004651/how-to-make-well-indexed-mysql-tables-join-effectively :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT to the query. That should help a lot.

I think if you change the query to this it will be faster:

```
select id, val from tbl where val = 'iii' order by val limit 10;
```

Comment: "limit" will only limit the number of rows recovered... it's faster, but if you need the full data set, it's useless. on the other hand, the "order by" will slow down the query, because the server has to sort the result set before sending the data

Comment: @Barranka: assuming he was selecting all rows, yes. Otherwise he was selecting a few random rows and the database doesn't know how to optimize that.

Comment: @jcho360: the database needs some ordering anyway, since he is using the index this will be just as fast in most cases and faster in some others.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a select based on two columns, but no index of both exists. Try adding a new index consisting of **both** id and val.

Comment: why would he need an index on id when he is searching only on val?